# Zeros of Eisenstein Series?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to, or has seen any literature on, analytically handling zeros of Eisenstein series?  Or perhaps, asymptotics on the zeros?  For example, I'm specifically interested in the zeros of

$$\frac{d E_{2} (\tau)}{d \tau} = \frac{\pi i }{6}\big(E_{2}^{2}(\tau) - E_{4}(\tau)\big).$$

This function is "quasi-modular" and from plots, it has an infinite sequence of zeros in the upper-half plane which accumulate at small imaginary part, and tend towards the origin it appears.  I doubt there are tabulated zeros of such a function, but perhaps someone has seen asymptotics somewhere?  Or maybe has other hints on how to find them?

BTW, I've tried finding the zeros numerically, and mathematica breaks down past the second or third zero, as this function is quite finicky at small imaginary value!

Comment: not sure it helps, but did you find the [Chazy equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chazy_equation) for it ?